# Can't install 'ks' package in R

Tags: r, package

I'm using R 3.0.2 and RStudio 0.98.945 for Mac.

Loading 'ks' package gives this error message.

```
Loading required package: rgl
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object          
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/r    gl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from:     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rgl’ could not be loaded
```

Loading 'rgl' package gives the same error message.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you are using  out-of-date versions of R and RStudio? (Otherwise I would suggest trying to reinstall pkg:rgl.)

Comment: And RStudio has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: This is not an R issue either, you are missing libGLU. However, I have got no clue how you go about installing it on a Mac (on Linux you would install the mesa-libGLU package).